# Erro ao enviar e-mail ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email, asp, smtp

Estou com um cliente e ele está com problemas para o envio de e-mail pela aplicação em asp. O código é o seguinte:

```
        string nomeRemetente = "Remetente";

        string emailRemetente = "email@email.remetente";
        string assuntoMensagem = assunto;
        MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
        objEmail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(nomeRemetente + "<" + emailRemetente + ">");


            objEmail.To.Add("email@destinatario.com.br");


        objEmail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
        objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        objEmail.Subject = assuntoMensagem;
        objEmail.Body = conteudoMensagem;
        objEmail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
        objEmail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient objSmtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

        objSmtp.Host = "smtp.meudominio";
        objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        objSmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailRemetente, "senha");
        objSmtp.Port = 587;

        try
        {
            objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            objEmail.Dispose();
        }
```

Ao enviar aparece o erro: "Sequência de comandos incorreta. A resposta do servidor foi: 5.0.3 : Client host rejected: Para envio de mensagens e necessaria autenticacao. Para saber como corrigir este erro acesse: http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Email_Locaweb_-_Envio_Autenticado /This mail server requires authentication", no qual esse link não funciona.

E quando eu coloco a função `objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;` informa o erro: "O certificado Remoto é inválido"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclua antes do método SEND

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Este código passa pela validação do certificado de segurança.

Use com segurança.

Espero que ajude.